# <10 users (windows 7 and Vista machines)--need basic network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, home-networking

A small office.

**Current environment:**
A few aging notebooks, one of which is connected to a printer by a USB cable.  No sharing of anything, but everyone is able to do web stuff via one central ordinary WPA/WPA2 PSK-secured 802.11n wireless router and modem, on a high speed internet connection.

**Desired setup:**

- Would like to access/share data files across any machines.
- Would like to access/use one or two common office peripherals from any machine.
- Would like to maintain the ability to get on the internet.  But secure; keep bad guys from outside away from the machines, while still maintaining the ability of users to share files and peripherals.
- Wireless/WLAN all or at least most of the way.
- Keep the Windows 7, Vista for now.
- Nothing fancy; budget; use existing OS and router capabilities where possible.

By now you can probably detect I know almost nothing about state of the art, contemporary small business networks.  But it's time to set one up.  What's the best strategy here?

Thanks for any ideas, assistance.

Comment: I'm not going to "try" anything without reading vetted ideas first.  All I know is connecting two Win 2000 machines in a peer to peer configuration years ago.  I'd like to follow best practices circa 2013, but am unsure what they are.  For one thing, I don't know whether I need to buy a firewall (even though users rely on Windows Firewall in their OSes), or not.  A lot has changed in the past few years, and I'm not up on it.  If someone has a diagram idea, I'd like to hear it.  I just want to build it right.  There actually isn't a whole lot of info out there for this day and age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be a small NAS. If it is for 12 or less persons, a simple 1TB nas should be more then enough. When connected with your router, everyone will be able to use it as an external drive and reach eachothers files.
You can also hook the printer up to the NAS so everyone will be able to print.

If you are on a tight budget, I would just go with Windows Firewall and MS Defender/Essentials for the time being. Those should be enough if noone goes to any weird sites ;)

Just make sure your wi-fi is password protected, all laptops are up to date with A/V and everything should be ok.

Scott

Comment: Thanks, I'd never heard of a NAS.  Interesting that you can hook a printer up to it too.  (I was wondering what happens when on occasion someone walks away with the notebook the peripheral was attached to. :-)

Comment: @user33666 Golly... Never heard of a NAS? For more info, just read the Wiki on it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage (not to be confused with "rapper" NAS)

Comment: Thanks.  By "and reach eachothers files," do you mean just what's been uploaded to the NAS as a common file area?  I'd still rely on Windows "File and Printer Sharing" network settings to get to files resident on individual notebook drives?  It's a stupid question but I've asked them before.

Comment: @user33666 Yeah, basically, you can see the NAS as an external harddrive. This drive can be accessed as a network share. Your best option is to have everyone upload their files to the NAS. With 2 disks, you can have a backup... If someone loses his/her laptop, or his/her drive gets corrupted, you are screwed. This way you have save backups.